# understanding hibernate cache

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, second-level-cache, query-cache

If I have this method in object class:

```
@OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
    cascade = { CascadeType.ALL },
    mappedBy = "object"  )
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(
    {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
@Column( nullable = false  )
public Set<ObjectEntry> getObjectEntries() {
    return this.objectEntries;
}
```

and I put `@cache` both on `ObjectEntry` and on `Object`

```
@Cache(usage =  CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Object extends HashCodeValidator {

@Cache(usage =  CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class ObjectEntry extends HashCodeValidator
```

Do I still need to put @cache on getObjectEntries like this:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(
    {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
@Column( nullable = false  )
@Cache(usage =  CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public Set<ObjectEntry> getObjectEntries() {
    return this.objectEntries;
}
```

Do I need to define cache for each query if I specifically add

```
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (...) Do I still need to put @cache on getObjectEntries like this:

Yes, you still have to **cache a collection** if you want to (that will be cached in a specific cache region).

> Do I need to define cache for each query if I specifically add `hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true`

From the reference documentation about the `hibernate.cache.use_query_cache` property (section [3.4. Optional configuration properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional)):

> Enables the query cache. Individual queries still have to be set cachable. **e.g.** `true`|`false`

So, yes, you still have to set a query *cachable* (by calling `setCacheable(true)` on a query or criteria object) if you want to - which is IMO a good thing.

Comment: one more question. 
Why do I need to cache the collection of getObjectEntries?
Won't it enlarge the memory too much?

Can Hibernate just save a refernce to the object that exists and not a reference to all the collecion?